# Control PWR and ACT LEDs on Raspberry Pi 2 B from Python

Tags: python, pi-2, led

I want to control the PWR and ACT LEDs on the Raspberry Pi 2 B using a Python script.

I found these lines but I don't know how to implement it in Python, can anyone help me please?

```
# Set the PWR LED to GPIO mode (set 'off' by default).
echo gpio | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger

# (Optional) Turn on (1) or off (0) the PWR LED.
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness

# Revert the PWR LED back to 'under-voltage detect' mode.
echo input | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger

# Set the ACT LED to trigger on cpu0 instead of mmc0 (SD card access).
echo cpu0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

Source: [Controlling PWR and ACT LEDs on the Raspberry Pi - Jeff Geerling](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/controlling-pwr-act-leds-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your program add:

`import os`

Then, to execute those commands in your question just use:

```
# Set the PWR LED to GPIO mode (set 'off' by default).
os.system("echo gpio | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger")

# (Optional) Turn on (1) or off (0) the PWR LED.
os.system("echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness")
os.system("echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness")

# Revert the PWR LED back to 'under-voltage detect' mode.
os.system("echo input | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/trigger")

# Set the ACT LED to trigger on cpu0 instead of mmc0 (SD card access).
os.system("echo cpu0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger")
```

Answer (score 1):

With my [pigpio Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Pi2B_leds.py
# Public Domain

import time
import pigpio

# The following values are unique to the Pi2B.

POWER_LED=35
ACTIVITY_LED=47
USB_POWER_GPIO=38

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
   exit(0)

stop = time.time() + 30

while time.time() < stop:

   pi.write(POWER_LED, 0)
   pi.write(ACTIVITY_LED, 1)

   time.sleep(3)

   pi.write(POWER_LED, 1)
   pi.write(ACTIVITY_LED, 0)

   time.sleep(1)

pi.stop()
```

Note that the green activity LED probably will not act as you expect.  The system will still be updating its value.

Comment: What about this line `echo gpio | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger`?  It will take the control of the act led, am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are right. You will need to do that as [Patrick Cook](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33979/patrick-cook) suggests or perhaps as a device tree entry (I'm not sure if it's possible, check /boot/overlays/README for leds).